# is there a way to make a DB diagram based on rails migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, diagram

is there a way to make a DB diagram of tables..columns and their relationship based on a rails app?

if not...are there tools that would do that for a postgresql DB on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [RailRoad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/) in the past which produces quite useful output.